# Deallocating rectangular 2d arrays gives error depending on dimensions

Tags: c++

I create a dynamically allocated 2d array and when I try to delete it, I get an error depending on the dimensions of the array.

If there are more rows than columns, there is no issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num_rows = 8;
    int num_cols = 6;

    char **charBoard = new char*[num_rows+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=num_cols; i++){
        charBoard[i] = new char[num_cols+1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <=num_rows; i++){
        delete[] charBoard[i];

    }   
    //free the main array
    delete[] charBoard;

return 0;   
}
```

If there are more columns than rows, I get an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num_rows = 4;
    int num_cols = 6;

    char **charBoard = new char*[num_rows+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=num_cols; i++){
        charBoard[i] = new char[num_cols+1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <=num_rows; i++){
        delete[] charBoard[i];

    }   
    //free the main array
    delete[] charBoard;

return 0;   
}
```

Then I get this error:
Aborted (core dumped)

I have no idea why.  Am I improperly deleting something?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <=num_rows; i++){` - should be num_cols. And lose the `<=` stuff.

Comment: Also `for(int i = 0; i<=num_cols; i++){` should be num_rows.

Comment: The <= is because the array is sized num_rows+1 and num_cols+1

Comment: "because the array is sized num_rows+1 and num_cols+1 " - why?

Comment: Still errors when I swap both num_rows and num_cols as you suggest.

Comment: Well, in my project I read a board size from a file.  I then need to print the board with the addition of labels for the axes.  Because of this I make the array bigger than the board so there is room for the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filling an array, you made a mistake with the variable name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num_rows = 4;
    int num_cols = 6;

    char **charBoard = new char*[num_rows+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= num_cols; i++) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^
        charBoard[i] = new char[num_cols+1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= num_rows; i++) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^
        delete[] charBoard[i];
    }   
    //free the main array
    delete[] charBoard;

    return 0;   
}
```

Here is the corrected version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num_rows = 4;
    int num_cols = 6;

    char **charBoard = new char*[num_rows+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= num_rows; i++) {
        charBoard[i] = new char[num_cols+1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= num_rows; i++) {
        delete[] charBoard[i];
    }   
    //free the main array
    delete[] charBoard;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Oh.  Ha.  So I do.  Thank you for the help!